# Preserve widget state when temporarily removed from tree in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, state, state-management, statefulwidget

I'm trying to preserve the state of a widget, so that if I temporarily remove the stateful widget from the widget tree, and then re-add it later on, the widget will have the same state as it did before I removed it. Here's a simplified example I have:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool showCounterWidget = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Material(
      child: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            showCounterWidget ? CounterButton(): Text("Other widget"),
            SizedBox(height: 16,),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("Toggle Widget"),
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                showCounterWidget = !showCounterWidget;
              });
                },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CounterButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CounterButtonState createState() => _CounterButtonState();
}

class _CounterButtonState extends State<CounterButton> {
  int counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialButton(
      color: Colors.orangeAccent,
      child: Text(counter.toString()),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          counter++;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Ideally, I would not want the state to reset, therefor the counter would not reset to 0, how would I preserve the state of my counter widget?

Comment: Your problem is that you're creating the CountButton each time the build is called, consider creating it in another scope & add it in build instead of creating it from scratch like CounterButton();

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The reason why the widget loose its state when removed from the tree temporarily is, as Joshua stated, because it loose its Element/State.

Now you may ask:

> Can't I cache the Element/State so that next time the widget is inserted, it reuse the previous one instead of creating them anew?

This is a valid idea, but no. You can't.
Flutter judges that as anti-pattern and will throw an exception in that situation.

What you should instead do is to keep the widget inside the widget tree, in a disabled state.

To achieve such thing, you can use widgets like:

- IndexedStack
- Visibility/Offstage

These widgets will allow you to keep a widget inside the widget tree (so that it keeps its state), but disable its rendering/animations/semantics.

As such, instead of:

```dart
Widget build(context) {
  if (condition)
    return Foo();
  else
    return Bar();
}
```

which would make `Foo`/`Bar` loose their state when switching between them

do:

```dart
IndexedStack(
  index: condition ? 0 : 1, // switch between Foo and Bar based on condition
  children: [
    Foo(),
    Bar(),
  ],
)
```

Using this code, then `Foo`/`Bar` will **not** loose their state when doing a back and forth between them.

Comment: I consider myself to have some knowledge about Flutter and I didn't know widgets loose their state when removed from widget tree even though the widget was previously instantiated. Maybe that should be noted on First Steps guides.

Answer (score 5):

Widgets are meant to store transient data of their own within their scope and lifetime.

Based on what you have provided, you are trying to re-create `CounterButton` **child widget**, by removing and adding it back to the widget tree.

In this case, the counter value that is under the `CounterButton` **was not saved** or **not saving** in the `MyHomePage` screen, the **parent widget**, without any reference to a view model or any state management within or at the top level.

**A more technical overview how Flutter renders your widgets**

Ever wonder what is the `key` if you try to create a constructor for a widget?

```dart
class CounterButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const CounterButton({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CounterButtonState createState() => _CounterButtonState();
}
```

keys (`key`) are identifiers that are automatically being handled and used by the Flutter framework to differentiate the instances of widgets in the widget tree. **Removing** and **adding** the widget (`CounterButton`) in the widget tree resets the `key` assigned to it, therefore the data it holds, its state are also removed.

> NOTE: No need to create constructors for the a `Widget` if it will only contain `key` as its parameter.

From the documentation:

> Generally, a widget that is the only child of another widget does not need an explicit key.

**Why does Flutter changes the key assigned to the CounterButton?**

You are switching between `CounterButton` which is a `StatefulWidget`, and `Text` which is a `StatelessWidget`, reason why Flutter identifies the two objects completely different from each other.

You can always use Dart Devtools to inspect changes and toggle the behavior of your Flutter App.

Keep an eye on `#3a4d2` at the end of the `_CounterButtonState`.
[image: image-1]

This is the widget tree structure after you have toggled the widgets. From `CounterButton` to the `Text` widget.
[image: image-2]

You can now see that the `CounterButton` ending with `#31a53`, different from the previous identifier because the two widgets are **completely different**.
[image: image-2]

**What can you do?**

I suggest that you save the data changed during runtime in the `_MyHomePageState`, and create a constructor in `CounterButton` with a callback function to update the values in the calling widget.

**counter_button.dart**

```dart
class CounterButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final counterValue;
  final VoidCallback onCountButtonPressed;

  const CounterButton({Key key, this.counterValue, this.onCountButtonPressed})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CounterButtonState createState() => _CounterButtonState();
}

class _CounterButtonState extends State<CounterButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialButton(
      color: Colors.orangeAccent,
      child: Text(widget.counterValue.toString()),
      onPressed: () => widget.onCountButtonPressed(),
    );
  }
}
```

Assuming you named your variable `_counterValue` in the `_MyHomePageState`, you can use it like this:

**home_page.dart**

```dart
_showCounterWidget
    ? CounterButton(
        counterValue: _counterValue,
        onCountButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _counterValue++;
          });
        })
    : Text("Other widget"),
```

In addition, this solution will help you re-use `CounterButton` or other similar widgets in other parts of your app.

I've added the complete example in [dartpad.dev](http://dartpad.dev/e8453e2497dab3cc7d4f5dd0ddd66595).

Andrew and Matt gave a great talk how Flutter renders widgets under the hood:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996ZgFRENMs

**Further reading**

- https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-what-are-widgets-renderobjects-and-elements-630a57d05208
- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Widget/key.html

Comment: That's off-topic. The question is not "why do I loose my state", but "how to preserve the state when voluntarily removing it from the tree". I would expect those coming here to know these facts, and be looking for something else.

Comment: Hi Rémi, thank you for sharing your thoughts. I think answering the "why" go hand in hand with the OP's "how". Based on the OP's question, he's clearly "trying" to preserve the widget state. I just assumed that he might not be familiar in-depth how widget rendering works, and that it might helpful as well if I try to get on a little deeper why such behavior happen. Appreciate your time, Rémi. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The real solution to this problem is state management. There are several good solutions for this available as concepts and flutter packages. Personally I use the [BLoC](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4074597-getting-started-with-the-bloc-pattern) pattern regularly.

The reason for this is that widget state is meant to be used for UI state, not application state. UI state is mostly animations, text entry, or other state that does not persist.

The example in the question is application state as it is intended to persist longer than the live time of the widget.

There is a little [Tutorial](https://smartstack.medium.com/flutter-state-management-bloc-pattern-counter-tutorial-f49b92cac1dd) on creating a BLoC based counter which could be a good starting point.