# Could not find the correct Provider above this Widget - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am new to Flutter and I am using Provider in my Flutter App and my main.dart file looks like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider_practice/screens/first_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider_practice/screens/second_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:provider_practice/counter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(

    home: ChangeNotifierProvider<Counter>(
      create: (context) => Counter(),
      child: FirstScreen(),
    ),

    routes: {
      "/first" : (context) => FirstScreen(),
      "/second" : (context) => SecondScreen(),
    },
  ));
}
```

My code works fine on FirstScreen() but when I navigate to SecondScreen() (by using Navigator.pushNamed()), I get the following error :

```
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building SecondScreen(dirty):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Counter> above this SecondScreen Widget
```

Is there anyway to fix this ? I am using Provider version ^5.0.0

first_screen.dart :-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:provider_practice/counter.dart';

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final counter = Provider.of<Counter>(context , listen: false);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("First Screen"),
      ),

      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Consumer<Counter>(
                  builder: (_ , counter , __) => Text("You pressed the button 
${counter.firstCounter} times.")
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: counter.firstIncrement,
                child: Text("Click Me"),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/second");
                },
                child: Text("Go to Second"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

second_screen.dart :-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:provider_practice/counter.dart';

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final counter = Provider.of<Counter>(context , listen: false);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Screen"),
      ),

      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Consumer<Counter>(
                  builder: (_ , counter , __) => Text("You pressed the button 
${counter.secondCounter} times.")
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: counter.secondIncrement,
                child: Text("Click Me"),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  //Navigator.maybePop(context);
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/first");
                  //Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text("Go to First"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

counter.dart :-

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Counter with ChangeNotifier {
  int firstCounter = 0;
  int secondCounter = 0;

  void firstIncrement() {
    firstCounter++;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void secondIncrement() {
    secondCounter++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find the correct Provider - Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57539094/could-not-find-the-correct-provider-flutter)

Comment: No it didn't answered my question.

Comment: Can you just tell me the changes which I need to do in my code ?

Comment: Can you provide some code of your second screen pls ?

Comment: I have added it now, check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing reproducable snippets of your code we cant help,
anyway you can return a multiprovider before material app and add your provider here

```
....
return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Counter>(
            create: (context) => Counter()),
]
child:MaterialApp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way.

```
runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AriticleProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => FavoriteProvider()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
```